# Keeping the original datasource in sync with downstream bindings

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

If I have a collection of fruits, and I pass one of them to a detail view, how do I edit that item so that both the item and it's original datasource are updated?

```
final class Merchant: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published
    var selection: Fruit?
    
    @Published
    var fruits = [
        Fruit(name: "Banana"),
        Fruit(name: "Apple")
    ]
}

struct FruitsView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(merchant.fruits) { fruit in
                Button {
                    merchant.selection = fruit
                } label: {
                    Text(fruit.name)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $merchant.selection, content: {
            FruitDetailView(item: $0)
        })
    }
}

struct FruitDetailView: View {

    let item: Fruit
    
    init(item: Fruit) {
        self.item = item
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Button("Press Me") {
                item.name = "Watermelon" // error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the item on `FruitDetailView` to a binding doesn't change the original datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you ask. This is one simple way using the model constructs you already have. It uses the `Merchant` `selection` to update the `Merchant` `fruits` data.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var merchant = Merchant()
    
    var body: some View {
        FruitsView().environmentObject(merchant)
    }
}

struct Fruit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

final class Merchant: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selection: Fruit? = nil {
        didSet {
            if selection != nil,
               let index = fruits.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == selection!.id}) {
                fruits[index].name = selection!.name
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Published var fruits = [Fruit(name: "Banana"), Fruit(name: "Apple")]
}

struct FruitsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(merchant.fruits) { fruit in
                Button {
                    merchant.selection = fruit
                } label: {
                    Text(fruit.name)
                }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $merchant.selection) { _ in
            FruitDetailView().environmentObject(merchant)
        }
    }
}

struct FruitDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(merchant.selection?.name ?? "no selection name")
            Button("Press Me") {
                merchant.selection?.name = "Watermelon"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

This is another way of keeping the model `in sync`. It uses a function `updateFruits` in the `Merchant` ObservableObject class, to update the model's data.

It separates the UI interaction part using a local `@State var selection: Fruit?` from the main data in the `Merchant` model.

```
final class Merchant: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fruits = [Fruit(name: "Banana"), Fruit(name: "Apple")]
    
    func updateFruits(with item: Fruit) {
        if let index = fruits.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
            fruits[index].name = item.name
        }
    }
}

struct FruitsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
    @State var selection: Fruit?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(merchant.fruits) { fruit in
                Button {
                    selection = fruit
                } label: {
                    Text(fruit.name)
                }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selection) { item in
            FruitDetailView(item: item).environmentObject(merchant)
        }
    }
}

struct FruitDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
    @State var item: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Button("Press Me") {
                item.name = "Watermelon"
                merchant.updateFruits(with: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems a shame to have to do this. Updating two datasources like this is a pain. In Objective-C you would just pass a pointer along.