# Binding an item within a collection

Tags: swiftui, binding

Looking at the following code

```
struct FruitDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
    @State var item: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Button("Press Me") {
                item.name = "Watermelon"
                merchant.updateFruits(with: item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A list of fruits was previously displayed to the user and when the user selected a fruit, that selected fruit was passed to this detail view. Where it now exists as a @State controlled property.

The merchant is also passed along because we want to keep the original array in sync. Updating both the fruit and the merchant is a pain. Is there no way to bind the fruit so that any modifications to it, also modifies the entry in the array of fruits on the merchant?

This post leads on from my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75493273/9400730).

In the world of Objective-C the following three items could be updated by just passing a pointer through the view hierarchy.

```
@implementation Merchant

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        
        Fruit *apple = [[Fruit alloc] initWithName: @"Apple"];
        Fruit *orange = [[Fruit alloc] initWithName: @"Orange"];
        Fruit *pear = [[Fruit alloc] initWithName: @"Pear"];
        
        self.fruits = @[apple, orange, pear];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@interface FruitDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Fruit * fruit;
@end

@implementation FruitDetailViewController

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.fruit.name = @"Cherry";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in your previous question, there are many ways to do things.

Here is yet another way, where only a `Binding Fruit`
is passed to the `FruitDetailView`. It really depends what you want to do.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var merchant = Merchant()
    
    var body: some View {
        FruitsView().environmentObject(merchant)
    }
}

struct Fruit: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

final class Merchant: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fruits = [Fruit(name: "Banana"), Fruit(name: "Apple")]
}

struct Selector: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var index: Int
}

struct FruitsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
    @State var selection: Selector?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(merchant.fruits.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(merchant.fruits[index].name) {
                    selection = Selector(index: index)
                }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selection) { selector in
            FruitDetailView(fruit: $merchant.fruits[selector.index])
        }
    }
}

struct FruitDetailView: View {
    @Binding var fruit: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(fruit.name)
            Button("Press Me") {
                fruit.name = "Watermelon"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

Here is another way using a `NavigationLink` to `goto` the `FruitDetailView` destination view,
instead of a `sheet`, using only bindings:

```
struct FruitsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var merchant: Merchant
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ForEach($merchant.fruits, id: \.id) { $fruit in
                NavigationLink(destination: FruitDetailView(fruit: $fruit)) {
                    Text(fruit.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```